# add column values according to value with if

Tags: python, if-statement

I would like to create following dataframe:

[image: Desired Dataframe]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['0','0','0','8.020833015','8.009259224','8.003472328','8.020833015','0','0','5','4.994213104','0','0','0','8.012152672','8.009259224','0'],
    'Step_ID': ['Step_1','Step_1','Step_1','Step_2','Step_2','Step_2','Step_2','Step_3','Step_3','Step_4','Step_4','Step_5','Step_5','Step_5','Step_6','Step_6','Step_7']})
print (df)
```

What I have is the column A and according to these values I would like to set the values in the column Step_ID.

Step_ID - it begins from Step_1. Then if the number is bigger then Step_2 (for all the number that are bigger than 0, till the zero values will be reached). Then to zero values should be Step_3 assigned and so on.

```
# add a Step ID
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['0','0','0','8.020833015','8.009259224','8.003472328','8.020833015','0','0','5','4.994213104','0','0','0','8.012152672','8.009259224','0']})
step = 0
value = None
def get_step(x):
    global step
    global value
    if x != value:
        value = x
        step += 1
    return f'Step_{step}'
df['Step_ID'] = df['A'].apply(get_step)
df.to_csv('test.csv' , index=None)
```

The code above does something similar, but only with unique numbers. Should be there one more "if"  - if value > 0 in order to perform desired functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see you implemented XOR gate but we need some customisation, I have added a new function to check.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['0','0','0','8.020833015','8.009259224','8.003472328','8.020833015','0','0','5','4.994213104','0','0','0','8.012152672','8.009259224','0']})
step = 0
value = None

def check(x, y):
    try:
        x = float(x)
        y = float(y)
        if x== 0 and y == 0:
            return 0
        elif x == 0 and y > 0:
            return 1
        elif x > 0 and y == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    except:
        return 1

def get_step(x):
    global step
    global value
    # if x != value:
    if check(x, value):
        step += 1
        value = x
    return f'Step_{step}'
df['Step_ID'] = df['A'].apply(get_step)
df.to_csv('GSH0211.csv' , index=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can adjust the threshold to the value you want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['0','0','0','8.020833015','8.009259224','8.003472328','8.020833015','0','0','5','4.994213104','0','0','0','8.012152672','8.009259224','0']})

df['A'] = df['A'].astype(float)
diff = df['A']-df['A'].shift().fillna(0)
threshold = 0.1
df['Step_ID'] = (abs(diff)>threshold).cumsum().add(1)
df['Step_ID'] =  'Step_' + df['Step_ID'].astype(str)
df
           A Step_ID
0   0.000000  Step_1
1   0.000000  Step_1
2   0.000000  Step_1
3   8.020833  Step_2
4   8.009259  Step_2
5   8.003472  Step_2
6   8.020833  Step_2
7   0.000000  Step_3
8   0.000000  Step_3
9   5.000000  Step_4
10  4.994213  Step_4
11  0.000000  Step_5
12  0.000000  Step_5
13  0.000000  Step_5
14  8.012153  Step_6
15  8.009259  Step_6
16  0.000000  Step_7
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much